# Using one directory with different aliases using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm redeveloping a site (replacing it with one based on CodeIgniter), which is currently a horrid mess of repeated procedural code, however, it has good search engine rankings. Because of this, I need to keep the exact same URL structure.

The company has many different quote pages, which are all essentially the same - so I've produced one clean version which can be used everywhere.

The quote system is now in a folder called /get-quote, but due to the old URLs being required, that folder mustn't be visible anywhere.

I'd like the following to happen, but don't know how to:

A user accessing /insurancequote.php should (on the server) load the /get-quote/ directory (which in turn will load the default CI route). The Base URL in CI should be http://www.mysite.com/insurancequote.php (I'm able to do that bit), so moving to step 2 would result in: http://www.mysite.com/insurancequote.php/step2 (which would map to /get-quote/step2).

Secondly, a user accessing /brokerquote.php should show mysite.com/broker in the address bar (redirect?), but on the server access /get-quote/broker.

Thirdly, a user accessing one of many broker-specific pages, e.g. mysite.com/brokername1.php or mysite.com/broker/brokername2.php (yep, they are scattered all over the place! - but I do know where each one is) should show mysite.com/broker/brokername1 or mysite.com/broker/brokername2. On the server, /get-quote/broker/brokername1 or /get-quote/broker/brokername2 should be accessed.

I don't think what I've written is completely clear, so maybe sudocode helps:

```
If '/insurancequote.php'
    Dont Redirect
    Use '/get-quote/'

If '/brokerquote.php'
    Redirect '/broker/'
    Use '/get-quote/broker/'

// Do the following (manually) for each broker
If '/brokername1.php'
    Redirect '/broker/brokername1/'
    Use '/get-quote/broker/brokername1/'

If '/brokers/bname2.php'
    Redirect '/broker/brokername2/'
    Use '/get-quote/broker/brokername2/'

If '/mybrokerpage.php'
    Redirect '/broker/mybroker/'
    Use '/get-quote/broker/mybroker/'
```

Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The risk you take is messing up your new clean code for historical reasons (and the guy coming next you will say, WTF, this is a mess!).

For me the right solution would be handling the url migration in apache and not in your application. Every refferenced url that you do not want to keep should get a **410 - Gone** message (think about referenced images for example) and every referenced page which have a new matching page should get a **301 - moved permanently** redirection on the right page. Then after some time as gone check the access log of your server, and if nobody checks the old url anymore then remove the rules.

If you know every old url and every matching url then use a matching url file (or **hash file**, faster) and manage the redirection 301 with **rewriteMap**. You can have a really big number of files in a hash file, the match should be fast. And it should be a temporary function, waiting for robots to fix the urls.

Comment: +1 agreed. it'd be a mess. 301 is the best way to handle this.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I'm having a very hard time convincing the client that 301s would be fine. I've accepted your answer as its obviously the best way, however I've looked at the apache docs and found the Alias statement... going to be using that to create insurancequote.php and brokerquote.php aliases to /get-quote. I'll have to make sure to leave a DEVELOPER_README.txt file around to explain the mess!